# SSH protocol version

Tags: java, ssh, protocols, j2ssh

Currently my application is working with J2SSH and now clients wants to migrate the existing server to IBM. This new server will support only SSH protocol version 2.

I have a query whether J2SSH will support SSH protocol version 2 ?.
Is there a way to find SSH protocol version in my application, currently my application is coded in Java environment with J2SSH for SSH/SFTP channels.

Comment: First decription I find about the library: `J2SSH is an object-orientated Java implementation of the SSH version 2 protocol.`.

Answer (score 0):

The original open source version of J2SSH only supports the SSH2 protocol. If you attempt to connect to an SSH1 server it will simply fail with a connection exception.

For security reasons you should probably consider migrating your code to the open source version of [J2SSH Maverick](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick). This is a similar API from the same author (that's me btw); the difference being that the new API is maintained and current whereas J2SSH has not been maintained for some time as its last release was in 2007.